# App Store Keeps Pushing The Same Updates

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update

I've got the following apps installed:

Text Wrangler 4.5.12
XCode 6.1.1
Microsoft Remote Desktop 8.0.12

I've installed the updates no less than 7 times in total in an attempt to get rid of this and it's still trying to push the same versions on me.

I was hoping that the recent OS X NTP Security Update would have fixed this (I was thinking that the date issue might be the cause) but these updates have just appeared again.

What can I do to stop this ridiculous situation?

Comment: I am having the same issue, have you ever found a solution? I think it updates but fails to mark them as updated somehow. My updates are for Skitch, Telegram, iMovie, Keynote, Numbers, Pages, Xcode, Cobook and I checked all of them, they seem to be up to date.

Comment: I uninstalled the apps completely and started again.